# Proactive Dialog with the Bot Framework from Group chat to Personal chat in MS Teams

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot, proactive

It's possible to send a proactive message (=private) to the sender of a message in a teams groups chat using the next part of code:

```
if (stepContext.Context.Activity.ChannelId == Channels.Msteams &&
    stepContext.Context.Activity.Conversation.IsGroup.HasValue &&
    stepContext.Context.Activity.Conversation.IsGroup.Value) {
        var teamConversationData = stepContext.Context.Activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>();
        var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(stepContext.Context.Activity.ServiceUrl), _credentialOptions.MicrosoftAppId, _credentialOptions.MicrosoftAppPassword);
        var userId = stepContext.Context.Activity.From.Id;
        var tenantId = teamConversationData.Tenant.Id;
        var parameters = new ConversationParameters
            {
                  Members = new[] { new ChannelAccount(userId) },
                  ChannelData = new TeamsChannelData
                  {
                       Tenant = new TenantInfo(tenantId),
                  },
            };
        var conversationResource = await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(parameters, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        var message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
        message.Text = "This is a proactive message. I've sent it from a group conversation.";
        await connectorClient.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(conversationResource.Id, (Activity)message, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}
```

But the issue is that **I also want to be able to trigger a Dialog for that calling user instead** of sending an Activity. It doesn't looks like that is possible after searching the web?
I played a bit with the code and found out that I could replace

```
await connectorClient.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(conversationResource.Id, (Activity)message, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

with

```
stepContext.Context.Activity.Conversation.Id = conversationResource.Id;
stepContext.Context.Activity.Conversation.IsGroup = false;
```

This way **it is possible to send dialogs to the private chat** of the sending user.

When I look in the database I can see the saved dialog stack of the user populated with the dialog (waiting for user interaction).
I can also see the group conversation dialog stack which remains empty, so the bot is still responsive in the group chat and for other users.

When the dialog ends I put the Conversation.Id and .IsGroup back to the previous group chat values I've saved on the context and it's able to pass the final answer(s) in the group chat just like I would like it to be.

Basically my code can switch to send stuff in private mid dialog, and at any other point in the dialog it can switch back to the group conversation.

**The question is about me changing the Conversation Id mid dialog. Is this something normal to do? Will this break stuff I didn't think about yet?**

Comment: Did you check this doc? - [Proactive Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive#best-practices-for-proactive-messaging)

Comment: Yeah, that is where I started from. But that only works for sending an Activity, not a Dialog. But I don't know how or why but now it all seems to work like want it. I probably was looking in a wrong database document. I'll update the question.

Comment: Try this approach -  [MS Team Proactive message](https://www.vrdmn.com/2020/02/microsoft-bot-framework-v4-send.html)

Comment: That is also the same as my initial approach, but is not able to send Dialogs, it can only send Activities.

Comment: We do not use this approach and it is normal to use it this way,

Comment: Yes but this way you can only tell a user something in private. By beginning a dialog you can ask the user for input in private instead. This is a big benefit, for example just for logging in so not the whole group is spammed by such things.

Comment: @Jordy - I tried this scenario my end and came to know it is successfully switching to Group & personal or reverse but if try to talk to bot again in group its continuing from where I left earlier(*when I switch personal*). Did you handle this as well in your code? I haven't tried to write some code to handle that

Comment: This might break the user experience by not starting dialog from first step.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT yes in our implementation we tested all cases with multiple people using the group bot, and it handles everything well in personal chat if we sent it there (because the dialogStack is moved to the private conversation) and the group bot doesn't block on private input this way in the group chat. Everything works atm, I only question if we are supposed/allowed to use the ConversationId this way and the implementation will not break in the feature.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT in your case it was continuing in the group because your dialogStack was saved in the group conversation and not in the personal conversation (because it should have the private conversationId set when it is saving the context when waiting for input from the user).

Comment: Correction: *Future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with this approach, but I think typically you'd start a new dialog rather than continue to use the same one.

I think any code accessing state prior to the hack would be persisted under the new id when state is saved. Middleware running prior to the turn, vs after the turn completes, would have two separate conversation ids.